# Firebase custom auth how to also create email and not only uid

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using cusotm auth in firebase and I generate my JWT token like this:

```
$userId = '1234';
$email = 'sample@email.com';
$key = 'giant_key_goes_here';

$payload = [
    'iss' => $email,
    'sub' => $email,
    'aud' => 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit',
    'iat' => time(),
    'exp' => time() + 60 * 60,
    'uid' => $userId,
    'claims' => [
        'uid' => $userId,
    ],
];

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'RS256');
```

When I later use that token in a ios device to login firebase will create new user.

But is it possible to also create a user email at the same time and not only a uid?